# tizen web app, launch another web application

Tags: launch, tizen

I was wondering if anyone knows how to launch a web app from another web app at when something like a button press event. I've seen code written in C I think but I would like it in Javascript, unless someone knows a way to run c in html ???

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using [App Control API](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/application.html) of Tizen Web App. Follow the example

**//main.js**

```
function onSuccess () {
    console.log(“App Launched”);}

function onError () {
    console.log(“Cannot Launch”);}

var appId=" com.samsung.clocksetting"; // app to be launched 

tizen.application.launch(appId, onSuccess, onError);
```

**// config.xml**

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much have been trying to get this to work for a while now

Comment: I've not had a long look at this, but is there a way to launch the app with a function call from within the launched app? .... like tizen.application.launch(appId, sayhello()).... but the sayhello() function is defined in the launched app not the launching app....

Comment: https://developer.tizen.org/forums/native-application-development/communication-between-native-service-or-app-and-widget
See this appControlReplyCallback example

Comment: I'm not sure I follow :/ are you able to give a javascript example?